# Way to launch the AR experience with Augmented Image tracking for then pass to Plane tracking

Tags: arcore

I want to use an image (~14cm square on the floor) as the coordinate origin for augmented objects.

Sadly, my experience using **ARCore's Augmented Image** functionality (holding the device at 1.5 to 2.5m away) shows that the tracking is not very robust in a real-world scenario, when marker (image) goes out of camera frame, or the distance from device to marker is larger than, let's say, 0.5m (that is, when features detail of image begin to blur).

Said that, when I use instead the **ARCore's Plane** tracking functionality, the experience is very robust over time and distance, but of course, model position is not perfectly defined, depending on a manual tweaking.

Analyzing the different tracking robustness, I suppose that Augmented Image tracking in not using such a comprehensive SLAM info, as Plane tracking does.

Having said that, I wonder if it is possible:
a) to start the AR experience generating an anchor with the Augmented Image technique, so the model is positioned automatically in the correct origin;
b) to pass immediately to a Plane tracking anchor, with the benefit of tracking robustness over time and distance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of ArCore >= 1.20 are already doing something like that with the newer cameras, but its not going to be very good until they start putting lidar in Android devices...